# Morse code translator: compilation error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, converters

I am currently working on a two way morse code translator program. I am not quite finished but when doing a test of the program I received multiple compilation errors. I have no idea what is wrong but am sure it is something simple. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code so far:

```
public class MorseCodeProject
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the conversion to be preformed.");
        System.out.println("Type 1 to convert English to Morse code.");
        System.out.println("Type 2 to convert Morse code to English.");

        int type = Input.getInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter the message to be converted.");

        String message = Input.getString();

        if(type == 1)
            EtoM(message);
        else
            MtoE(message);
    }
    public static void EtoM(String message)
    {
            String translation[] = new String[message.length()];
            String y;

            for(int x = 0; x < message.length(); x++)
            {
                y = message.substring(x, x + 1);

                switch(y)
                {
                    case "a":
                        translation[x] = ".-";
                        break;
                    case "b":
                        translation[x] = "-...";
                        break;
                    case "c":
                        translation[x] = "-.-.";
                        break;
                    case "d":
                        translation[x] = "-..";
                        break;
                    case "e":
                        translation[x] = ".";
                        break;
                    case "f":
                        translation[x] = "..-.";
                        break;
                    case "g":
                        translation[x] = "--.";
                        break;
                    case "h":
                        translation[x] = "....";
                        break;
                    case "i":
                        translation[x] = "..";
                        break;
                    case "j":
                        translation[x] = ".---";
                        break;
                    case "k":
                        translation[x] = "-.-";
                        break;
                    case "l":
                        translation[x] = ".-..";
                        break;
                    case "m":
                        translation[x] = "--";
                        break;
                    case "n":
                        translation[x] = "-.";
                        break;
                    case "o":
                        translation[x] = "---";
                        break;
                    case "p":
                        translation[x] = ".--.";
                        break;
                    case "q":
                        translation[x] = "--.-";
                        break;
                    case "r":
                        translation[x] = ".-.";
                        break;
                    case "s":
                        translation[x] = "...";
                        break;
                    case "t":
                        translation[x] = "-";
                        break;
                    case "u":
                        translation[x] = "..-";
                        break;
                    case "v":
                        translation[x] = "...-";
                        break;
                    case "w":
                        translation[x] = ".--";
                        break;
                    case "x":
                        translation[x] = "-..-";
                        break;
                    case "y":
                        translation[x] = "-.--";
                        break;
                    case "z":
                        translation[x] = "--..";
                        break;
                    case "1":
                        translation[x] = ".----";
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        translation[x] = "..---";
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        translation[x] = "...--";
                        break;
                    case "4":
                        translation[x] = "....-";
                        break;
                    case "5":
                        translation[x] = ".....";
                        break;
                    case "6":
                        translation[x] = "-....";
                        break;
                    case "7":
                        translation[x] = "--...";
                        break;
                    case "8":
                        translation[x] = "---..";
                        break;
                    case "9":
                        translation[x] = "----.";
                        break;
                    case "0":
                        translation[x] = "-----";
                        break;
                    case " ":
                        translation[x] = "|";
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                for(int z = 0; z < message.length(); z++)
                {
                    System.out.println(translation[z]);
                }
            }

    }
    public static void MtoE(String message)
    {
        int segments = 1;
        char segment1;
        int x = 0;

        for(x = 0; x < message.length(); x++);
        {
            if(message.charAt(x) = "|")
            {
                segments += 1;
            }
        }

        String segmentedMessage[] = new String[segments];
        int j = 0;
        int k;

        for(int y = 0; y < segments; y++)
        {
            for(k = j; k < message.length(); k++)
            {
                if(message.charAt(k) == "|")
                {
                    segementedMessage[y] = message.substirng(j, k);
                    j = k;
                }
            }
        }

        String segment;
        String translation[] = new String[segments]

        for(int c = 0; c < segments; c++)
        {
            segment = segmentedMessage[c];

            switch(segment)
            {
                    case ".-":
                        translation[c] = "a";
                        break;
                    case "-...":
                        translation[c] = "b";
                        break;
                    case "-.-.":
                        translation[c] = "c";
                        break;
                    case "-..":
                        translation[c] = "d";
                        break;
                    case ".":
                        translation[c] = "e";
                        break;
                    case "..-.":
                        translation[c] = "f";
                        break;
                    case "--.":
                        translation[c] = "g";
                        break;
                    case "....":
                        translation[c] = "h";
                        break;
                    case "..":
                        translation[c] = "i";
                        break;
                    case ".---":
                        translation[c] = "j";
                        break;
                    case "-.-":
                        translation[c] = "k";
                        break;
                    case ".-..":
                        translation[c] = "l";
                        break;
                    case "--":
                        translation[c] = "m";
                        break;
                    case "-.":
                        translation[c] = "n";
                        break;
                    case "---":
                        translation[c] = "o";
                        break;
                    case ".--.":
                        translation[c] = "p";
                        break;
                    case "--.-":
                        translation[c] = "q";
                        break;
                    case ".-.":
                        translation[c] = "r";
                        break;
                    case "...":
                        translation[c] = "s";
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        translation[c] = "t";
                        break;
                    case "..-":
                        translation[c] = "u";
                        break;
                    case "...-":
                        translation[c] = "v";
                        break;
                    case ".--":
                        translation[c] = "w";
                        break;
                    case "-..-":
                        translation[c] = "x";
                        break;
                    case "y-.--:
                        translation[c] = "y";
                        break;
                    case "--..":
                        translation[c] = "z";
                        break;
                    case ".----":
                        translation[c] = ".----";
                        break;
                    case "..--":
                        translation[c] = "..---";
                        break;
                    case "...--":
                        translation[c] = "...--";
                        break;
                    case "....-":
                        translation[c] = "....-";
                        break;
                    case ".....":
                        translation[c] = ".....";
                        break;
                    case "-....":
                        translation[c] = "-....";
                        break;
                    case "--...":
                        translation[c] = "--...";
                        break;
                    case "---..":
                        translation[c] = "---..";
                        break;
                    case "----.":
                        translation[c] = "----.";
                        break;
                    case "-----":
                        translation[c] = "-----";
                        break;
                    case "|":
                        translation[c] = " ";
                    default:
                        break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what are the errors? also: `if(message.charAt(x) = "|")` should be `if(message.charAt(x) == "|")` (double equals signs)

Comment: He or she is not closing case **"y-.--:** that string

Comment: While this should work (after debugging), it adopts a very C-ish style.  Couldn't a lookup table be used instead of a large case statement?  The lookup table could be used to build its own inverse.

Comment: If it's giving errors, you should post them so we can see. Compiler error messages are usually straightforward and easy to solve (in fact, if you have no idea what is wrong, that should be where you start).

Comment: @Alfie `if(message.charAt(x) == "|")` won't compile since you have a char on one side of the `==` operator and a string on the other.

Comment: @arshajii yes my mistake, should be `== '|'`, not `== "|"`

Answer (score 3):

Here are the problems I found:

1.

```
if(message.charAt(x) = "|")
```

should likely be

```
if(message.charAt(x) == '|')
```

The same goes for `if(message.charAt(k) = "|")`. Recall that `=` is *assignment* whereas `==` is *comparison*, and that `charAt()` returns a `char` as opposed to a `String`, so we compare with `'|'` and not `"|"` (you should use `.equals()` for strings anyway).

---

2.

```
segementedMessage[y] = message.substirng(j, k);
```

`substring` is mispselled here, and so is `segmentedMessage` (which you declare with the correct spelling earlier).

---

3.

```
String translation[] = new String[segments]
```

You're missing a `;` at the end of this line.

---

4.

```
case "y-.--:
```

You're missing a closing `"` at the end of that string (should be `case "y-.--":`).